# Firebase Firestore Save Placemark vs only Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I need to save in my table two Placemarks. One for the location and one for the destination.
What I'm doing now is that im creating a dictionary with all the details as below:

```
let location: [String: Any] = [
    "coordinate": GeoPoint(latitude: item.location.coordinate.latitude , longitude: item.location.coordinate.longitude),
    "name": item.location.name,
    "isoCountryCode": item.location.isoCountryCode,
    "country": item.location.country,
    ...etc 
]
```

and then Im saving this to Firestore. Then Im parsing this to my Placemark model(not CLPlacemark).

Recently I was thinking if it better to save only the coordinates and then to use GeoCoder 
`geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in` to fetch the placemark.

So which is actually better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to save only the coordinates. That way if there's something like a location name change, the saved placemark won't become outdated.